# Unable to View Uploaded Images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, paperclip, polymorphism

I am trying to get multiple images to upload and to display on the page.

I believe i have them uploading but i am having trouble displaying them.

I have searched and searched. tring to figure out how to get these images to display.

uploading via paperclip.

here is my coding:

As you can see i do have images in my image table

```
Image.last
  Image Load (34.6ms)  SELECT  "images".* FROM "images"   ORDER BY "images"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<Image id: 16, car_id: nil, created_at: "2014-07-23 05:32:47", updated_at: "2014-07-23 05:32:47", image_file_name: "15416359_large.jpg", image_content_type: "image/jpeg", image_file_size: 65742, imageable_id: 2, imageable_type: "Car">
```

form partial for edit and new.

```
<%= form_for(@car, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
  <% if @car.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@car.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this car from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @car.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
    <div class="newPaperclipFiles">

      <%= f.fields_for :images do |image| %>

          <% if image.object.new_record? %>
              <%= image.file_field :image %>
          <% end %>

      <% end %>

    </div>

    <div class="existingPaperclipFiles">

      <% f.fields_for :images do |image| %>

          <% unless image.object.new_record? %>

              <div class="thumbnail">
                <%= link_to( image_tag(image.object.image.url(:thumb)), image.object.image.url(:original) ) %>

              </div

          <% end %>

      <% end %>
    </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Show view

```
<% fields_for :images do |image| %>

    <% unless image.object.new_record? %>

        <div class="thumbnail">
          <%= link_to( image_tag(image.object.image.url(:thumb)), image.object.image.url(:original) ) %>

        </div

    <% end %>

<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_car_path(@car) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', cars_path %>
```

image Model

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
  has_attached_file :image,
                    :styles => {
                        :thumb=> "200x200#",
                        :small  => "300x300>",
                        :large => "600x600>"
                    }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
end
```

car model

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images, as: :imageable, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

Cars Controller

```
  def show
    @car = Car.find(params[:id])
    10.times { @car.images.build }
  end

  # GET /cars/new
  def new
    @car = Car.new
    10.times { @car.images.build }
  end

  # GET /cars/1/edit
  def edit
    @car = Car.find(params[:id])
    10.times { @car.images.build }
  end
```

DB Schema

```
  create_table "cars", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "imageable_id"
    t.string   "imageable_type"
  end

 add_index "cars", ["imageable_id", "imageable_type"], name: "index_cars_on_imageable_id_and_imageable_type", using: :btree

  create_table "images", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "car_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.integer  "imageable_id"
    t.string   "imageable_type"
  end

  add_index "images", ["imageable_id", "imageable_type"], name: "index_images_on_imageable_id_and_imageable_type", using: :btree
```

THE ANSWER WAS

```
<% @car.images.each do | image | %>
  <%= link_to image_tag(image.image.url(:thumb)), image.image.url(:original) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What's the problem? It just doesn't show up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Show**

If you're not able to see the images in your `show` action, the simple explanation is that you're calling `fields_for` (which is notorious for not showing up without showing any exceptions):

```
<% fields_for :images do |image| %>

    <% unless image.object.new_record? %>

        <div class="thumbnail">
          <%= link_to( image_tag(image.object.image.url(:thumb)), image.object.image.url(:original) ) %>

        </div

    <% end %>

<% end %>
```

This is not going to work for you - you'll be better using the following:

```
#app/controllers/cars_controller.rb
Class CarsController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @car = Car.find params[:id]
   end
end

#app/views/cars/show.html.erb
<%= link_to image_tag(@car.images.first.image.url(:thumb)), @car.images.first.image.url(:original) %>
```

---

**Syntax**

It looks like you have a problem with the *syntax* of Rails, which you'll need to correct

If you want to show an image, you just have to use the [`image_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag) helper. You're currently trying to use `form` helper methods to display the image, which will only result in problems like the ones you're seeing

The way to fix that is to just use the image_tag helper on its own:

```
<%= image_tag "your_path_to_the_image" %>
```

I'd definitely recommend you look out for the ways to research the syntax of Ruby / Rails, so you're able to create the image correctly

Comment: I used your above example and it works for the first picture. but how would i do a loop thru all the pictures. without having to manually code each one... some might have 4 some might have 10